# Iterating by Value in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose a class `Object` exists.

I now have `vector<Object> vec`

If I now do in some part of my code:

```
for(auto p : vec){
   //something with p
}
```

Does this make a **new object** p for every object that actually in the iterator? Or does it actually just go through the actual objects in the list? I'm asking because I've also seen `auto& p`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will make a copy of each item, to have a reference you should do:

```
for (auto& p : vec) {}
```

Also, if you want to protect items from any change, you can have `const` to reference:

```
for (const auto& p : vec) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The range based for loop you have

```
for(auto p : vec) /* ... */
```

copies every element in `vec` into the loop variable `p`. Hence, any changes you apply to `p` does not affect the elements in `vec`. And yes, if you change the loop to

```
for (auto& p : vec) /* ... */
```

then `p` is a reference to the `vec` elements, and changes applied to `p` are changes you apply to the corresponding `vec` element.